# Tracking file downloads per username

Tags: php, .net, download, wordpress, recommendation-engine

We are looking to put together a site to offer base marketing files to a select number of users, each of whom will have their own username.

We want to be able to offer one-click downloads of these files in a more informative environment than a simple FTP client (we are expecting this to be used by people without much technical expertise, so we want a HTML page we can customize with sample images and descriptions).  We also want to track which user has downloaded which file(s).

We are looking for a solution we can host on our own servers (we can run php, Wordpress, or .NET) for a relatively low cost.  If we were looking to spend much money on it, we'd just build the thing ourselves.

Are there any low-or-no cost packages out there we could stand up on our server that offer registration/membership, one-click downloads of electronic media, and can track which members download which media?

Comment: I've been googling, but it is really hard to get useful results with the fairly generic keywords I'm using ('download', 'tracking', 'user-based', 'hosted', etc)

Comment: You are really looking for a document management system (DMS). Searching for "document management php" or "file management php" lists various options.

Comment: @bspellmeyer: THANK YOU - that is helping in my search immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [digital downloads](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/) plugin for Wordpress if that was your choice of platform but otherwise, something like this could be easily implemented in PHP using a unique key for your user - if you are looking for a developer, [I'm available](http://jakebown.com/contact)!

Comment: I am a developer :-)  Our client, however, is adverse to the cost of a full custom site.  Also, I'm not really sure that SO is supposed to be used for self-promotion.